# Javascript event triggers based on local clock

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a scenario where one client PC will be driving multiple LCD displays, each showing a single browser window. These browser windows show different data which is on an animated cycle, using jquery.

I need to ensure that both browsers can be synched to rotate at exactly the same time, otherwise they'll animate at different times.

So my question is - can I trigger jquery to alternate the content based on the local PC clock?

eg each time the clock seconds == 0, show version 1, each time clock seconds == 30, show version 2 etc?

Comment: `if (getSeconds() == 0) { } else if (getSeconds() == 30) { }`

Comment: That doesn't put them in sync. I need an event to trigger precisely when the seconds turn 30 or 0

Comment: @hud, I was mostly just informing you about the `getSeconds()` method, which is a method of a `Date` object, by the way. You don't actually want to poll.

Comment: @JustinSatyr if you use `getSeconds()` then one second will be the margin of error in the timing.  That's pretty poor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is (in my experience) the most precise way of getting timers to trigger as closely as possible to a clock time:

```
// get current time in msecs to nearest 30 seconds
var msecs = new Date().getTime() % 30000;

// wait until the timeout
setTimeout(callback, 30000 - msecs);
```

Then, in the callback, once everything is done, do the same again to trigger the next event.

Using `setInterval` causes other problems, including clock drift.  The calculation based on the current time accounts for the time executing the callback itself.

You'll still also need to use `Date().getTime()` as well to figure out which frame of your animation to show.

The whole thing would look something like this:

```
function redraw() {
    var interval = 30000;

    // work out current frame number
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var frame = Math.floor(now / interval) % 2; // 0 or 1

    // do your stuff here
    .. some time passes

    // retrigger
    now = new Date().getTime();
    setTimeout(redraw, interval - (now % interval));
}

redraw();
```

working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/JPu4R/

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: yes you can.

- Use `Date.getTime()` to monitor time
- Trigger your js function every 30 seconds

Comment: are you seriously suggesting that he _poll_ for the time changing?

Comment: That wouldn't put the two browsers in sync, because I couldn't ensure they polled at the same times

Answer (score 0):

Why not launch one window from the other - that way the parent window will have complete control over when the animation starts, because they are in the SAME PROCESS. No clocks required.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.
This way, no matter when you launched the different browsers, their rotations would be in sync.

```
var t=setInterval("check()",1000);
function check(){
    var d = new Date();
    if(d.getSeconds()  == 0)
    {
        alert('do something');
    } else if (d.getSeconds() == 30) 
    {
        alert('do something else');
    }
}
```